# PHP: print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=' with URL parameters

Tags: php

How do I create this string with URL parameters?  What I want is something like:

```
print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://domain.com?a=1&b=2">';
```

But that doesn't pass my second parameter correctly.  I get a ")" instead of a b.  What am I doing wrong?

I've tried `&amp;` instead of the ampersand, but that doesn't work either,

Comment: why to use meta refresh with zero delay at all?

Comment: So you're saying do ... content="url=http://domain.com?a=1&b=2">... ?

Comment: Using the exact code you've supplied works without an issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://domain.com?a=1&b=2'>";
```

or even

```
header ("Location: url=http://domain.com?a=1&b=2");
```

since you are using 0 as delay

Comment: header is not good if there were a POST data, because pushing Refresh will resend the data...in the case with <meta it will redirect to another page, and repeating press of Refreshh will not send the same data again

Comment: Header is perfectly fine with POST data; pushing refresh after a redirect will no cause it to be resubmitted. This is why the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern is so popular.

Comment: @Aziz you just have no idea what are you talking about

Comment: @YourCommonSense Can able to tell or give link to check difference for `header() and echo'<meta http-equiv=...`

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using 0 delay for the `<meta>` refresh, why don't you just use a HTTP `Location` redirect?

```
<?php
   header('Location: http://domain.com?a=1&b=1');
```

and if it's in the middle of a page you have to rewrite your program to make it SENSIBLE

Answer (score 1):

Why shouldn't you code work? Cause it does work...

If I run your code I go to:

```
domain.com?a=1&b=2
```

Answer (score -3):

```
print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://domain.com?a=1&b=2'>";
```

there are differences between `'` and `"`

Comment: This takes me to domain.com without the parameters.