# Redirecting page not working properly - get data and redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to make a middle page between the visitor and the content to take the data of the content for statistics.

But something not working properly some of the entries not counting and not redirecting. code included.

May be there is a better way do to the save & redirect.

I expect to to get the best solution of my problem maybe with new code, or its the user agent class problem.

```
//Vars
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
include("../../includes/functions.php");
$BNL = new MBNL();
$ua = new Browser();


if(isset($_GET['id']) AND !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    try {
        $id = $BNL->protect($_GET['id']);
        $select = $db->query("SELECT `default_cost`,`url`,`id` FROM `links` WHERE `unique_id` = '{$id}'");
        if ($select->rowCount() > 0) {
            $row = $select->fetch();
            $url = $row['url'];
            $ip = getIP();
            $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            $host_name = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            $browser = $ua->getBrowser();
            $browser_version = $ua->getVersion();
            $os = getOs();
            $ip_info = ip_info($ip); 
            if(isset($_GET['data1'])) {
                $data1 = $BNL->protect($_GET['data1']);
            } else { $data1 = "";}
            if(isset($_GET['data2'])) {
                $data2 = $BNL->protect($_GET['data2']);
            } else { $data2 = "";}
            if(isset($_GET['data3'])) {
                $data3 = $BNL->protect($_GET['data3']);
            } else { $data3 = "";}
            if(isset($_GET['data4'])) {
                $data4 = $BNL->protect($_GET['data4']);
            } else { $data4 = "";}
            if(isset($_GET['data5'])) {
                $data5 = $BNL->protect($_GET['data5']);
            } else { $data5 = "";}

            if(isset($_GET['country'])) {
                $country = $BNL->protect($_GET['country']);
            } 
            if(isset($_GET['ip'])) {
                $ip = $BNL->protect($_GET['ip']);
            } 
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `entries` (`link_id`, `ip`, `country`, `city`, `country_code`, `os`, `browser`, `browser_version`, `hostname`, `useragent`, `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4`, `data5`, `default_cost`, `timestamp`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->execute(array($row['id'], $ip, $ip_info['country'], $ip_info['city'], $ip_info['country_code'], $os, $browser, $browser_version, $host_name, $useragent, $data1, $data2, $data3, $data4, $data5, $row['default_cost'], time()));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`ip`, `timestamp`) VALUES(?, ?)");
        $stmt->execute(array( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], time()));
    }


    echo '<head><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.$url.'"></head>';

}
```

Comment: if you wanna redirect you can use [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in php `header('Location: $url');`

Comment: @RasaMohamed I know that way but the place i sent the traffic not counting when i sent by header

Comment: so ur able differentiate this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650406/php-print-meta-http-equiv-refresh-content-0url-with-url-parameters)